Why can't VM be bridged despite restoring defaults in VMWare Network Editor?
I need to bridge my VM as there is a (physical) machine I need my VM to connect to via the  host ethernet adapter. Therefore, I need to use Bridged networking mode but the VMnet0 interface is not showing up in my host internet connections (only VMnet1 and VMnet8 show up). I am using VMWare and have tried going into the Virtual Network Editor to restore defaults for VMnet0 as recommended in other similar posts I have read (see link below to SuperUser post) as well as setting Bridged mode from automatic to Bridged to my ethernet adapter. However, VMnet0 does not appear and I am unable to connect to the other machine I need my VM to interface with. I would really appreciate your help, Thank you very much.
Post Link: vmware workstation - cannot change network to bridged
